# How to define priority to display symfony2 Form errors

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, assert

I need to set the priority with which errors are displayed. I use Assert anotation and Assert Callback on entities to validate the forms.

Is there a way to define a priority on these assert, in the annotation or somewhere else ?

Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might be able to if you change the order of the properties.

Comment: The problem is that i have somme errors that are set in the annotation of the property and some others that are set in a Assert callback function. So, i can't manage the order.

Comment: It's all down via reflection so it still might help. It wouldn't take long to test it out.